# Classroom platonism 

Tags: mathematics-education

I'd like to know whether any form a certain hypothesis about the
learning of higher mathematics has entered the mathematical or
educational literature.  I'll frame the hypothesis here but not defend
it since this is not a blog-in-disguise; likewise I'm not soliciting
debate.

This hypothesis opposes to some degree the common shibboleth which
holds that "mastering abstraction" constitutes the single major
plateau which undergraduate mathematics students must, but often do
not, scale.

For the sake of making the distinction,  I'll first flesh out what I
mean by "mastering abstraction."  Generally speaking, abstraction means
reducing to essentials. So mastering mathematical abstraction breaks
into two major challenges: learning modelling and learning formal
work.  Modelers must first know how to decide what they may safely
ignore and then how to select or construct formal systems that
adequately capture what remains.  With a formal system in hand,
getting answers requires skill with its internal operation, sometimes
despite the loss of intuition that arises from distance to the
original situation.  Of course a feedback cycle often arises --
"answers" from formal work can demand systemic revision of the
formalism.

On the the current hypothesis, namely that something else constitutes the major glass ceiling for advance mathematics students.  I'll call that something else cognitive platonization. (If someone else has already coined a better name I'd like to know!)  So cognitive platonization occurs when mathematicians confer objecthood on the collection of some or all configurations of a known object.  Examples abound: taking all solutions of certain differential equations as elements of a vector space, forming (iterated) power sets and cumulative hierarchies in set theory, studying state spaces in dynamical systems, moduli spaces in geometry, homology and cohomology groups or Stone-Cech compactifications in topology. Like abstraction, cognitive platonization often induces a loss of intuition due to distance from the original situation, but I contend a different sort of distance.  Abstraction involves reasoning away from a picture you may feel afraid to lose; cognitive platonization involves reasoning on the way to a picture you may fear will never congeal.

As an aside, I chose the name because some radical philosophers
challenge the very "existence" of just these sort of things I see
students struggling to comprehend.

I'd like to know several things:

1) Does the challenge of teaching cognitive platonization (known by
whatever name) have a *theoretical* literature?

2) Does cognitive platonization have a *practical* literature, meaning
materials aimed directly at students, perhaps at the (American)
college sophomore level?

3) Do any books from the popular science genre frame this issue and do
a good job at communicating its essentials to a wide-audience?

4) What testable implications of the hypothesis can anyone suggest?
Might success or failure with, say, abstract algebra or measure theory
correlate with a student's response to tasks, otherwise unrelated to
that subject matter, that indicate their ability or willingness to
embrace this process of conferring objecthood?  If so, what sort of
tasks?

Final note: I'm asking here because most mathematics education research looks at K-12 teaching and learning, or perhaps calculus.  Almost all writing about teaching higher mathematics comes from practicing mathematicians.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that you characterize as *radical* those philosophers who challenge something you put in scare quotes.

Comment:  I used scare quotes because I'm philosophically skeptical about any single unified concept of existence. For example, a radical philosopher might contend that $10^{10^{10^{10}}}$ does not exist (something like this comes up in Edward Nelson's Radically Elementary Probability Theory). And we might all agree that unicorns do not exist. But I don't find it clear that "not exist" means the same thing in both claims.

Comment: Not an answer, just a comment about cognitive platonization: I've seen this problem at a much lower level of mathematics. Children who know perfectly well how to add 3 dogs + 2 dogs, or 3 books + 2 books, can still fail to see how to add fractions like 3 tenths + 2 tenths.  The missing step, treating the abstract tenths like the concrete dogs and books, seems to be an instance of what you call cognitive platonization.

Comment: Trying to understand your terminology better: Would you say that Descartes's use of the term "imaginary number" was symptomatic of a resistance to cognitive platonism? Was the historical lateness of the discovery of non-Euclidean geometries perhaps due in part to a discomfort with cognitive platonism? Would you characterize Emmy Noether as a master of cognitive platonization? If so, then it seems professional mathematicians have also had trouble with cognitive platonization historically, and maybe you're witnessing "ontogeny recapitulating phylogeny" in the classroom?

Comment: To platonize X, don't you necessarily abstract Y? If you want to view the class of all X as really a certain kind of Y, you have to reduce your picture of Y to its essential components and formally check that the class of all X satisfies those conditions?

Comment: I would have thought that these conceptual difficulties arise because of the way our brains function. In which perhaps we should try to translate the issues into psychology rather than philosophy?

Comment: The closest I've heard to cognitive platonization is the *reification* mentioned (if I remember right) in William Byers's "How mathematicians think". The idea there was that a process (or processes) is (are) considered as an object. As for the abstraction obstruction, I think I still suffer from that one...as I'm not yet able to think like Grothendieck :) 

Comment: @Andreas It strikes me that teachers of small children may either choose to concretize tenths (say via slices of pie) or, say, ask how to add 3 wizzlewazzles + 2 wizzlewazzles to get across the idea that the answer that it doesn't even matter (for this) what tenths are.
I don't see treating abstract tenths like concrete dogs and books as cognitive platonization, but I do see cognitive platonization in the grammatical transition from "5 tenths are..." to "5/10 is..."  

Comment: @Timothy The trouble with "imaginary numbers" strikes me as analogous to civil unions and gay marriage...an struggle about essential attributes and privilege.  The old idea that full-fledged numbers should measure or count seems reasonable.  Had the originators not called $\sqrt{-1}$ a "number" the whole historical chapter might have unfolded without a fuss.  Agree about non-Euclidean geometry - the whole geometry becomes the object of study rather than the circles and triangles...  

Comment: ...Agree about Emmy Noether...and also Poincaré.  You can read Poincaré selling platonization right at the beginning of Analysis Situs.

Comment: @Will Maybe I don't understand, but you haven't convinced me.  I would agree that after platonizing configurations of $X$ to get $Y$ one then has the option of abstracting $Y$ away from its association with $X$.  For example this happens when we forget the coordinates.  And of course the elements of $X$ to start with may represent abstractions of some sort.  Abstracting and platonizing work together very well, but I see a distinction.  And it does seem to me that the latter represents the most persistent difficulty for my students.

Comment: @Chris  I'm not sure I read you.  I will say, having tried to teach some philosophy of mathematics to undergraduates, that I don't think I would have served them well if my course induced them to align as formalists, Platonist, intuitionists or whatever.  All the major philosophical positions capture vital aspects of mathematical practice and I believe that the sense of conflict arises because we overload words like "existence" and "identity" and then forget that we did.

Comment: @David: In all your examples, Y is something concrete. A teacher would be insane to teach function spaces before "we live in R^3", power sets before sets of letters, numbers, etc., and state spaces and moduli spaces before donuts and coffee cups. So the student must abstract away their original concrete concept for Y. They must replace their concept with its formal properties, and see that X satisfies its formal properties. I am not saying that abstraction is the fundamental problem in platonization. I am just saying that abstraction is a key component of platonization.

Answer (score 6):

The platonization you are looking at seems related to the idea of **reification** that appears in mathematics education literature (roughly the compression of a mathematical process to a mathematical object). Note: This is clearly distinct from what you are asking about, but shares the feature of bestowing objecthood on something in a way that requires the shift to (what is at first) a radically different viewpoint.

A few things on this that may be helpful can be found [here](https://www.msu.edu/~sfard/).

Particularly, here are a [couple](http://apophenia.wdfiles.com/local--files/start/Sfard-ReificationAsTheBirthOfMetaphor.pdf) of [papers](http://academic.sun.ac.za/mathed/174/GainsAndPitfalls.pdf) on reification.

Comment: My sole experience with the term reification (before encountering Jon Bannon's usage) was in a book of Stephen Jay Gould (The Mismeasure of Man, if my memory serves me), where he mentioned its misuse to create things which weren't really there to help indicate intelligence.  A weak but worrying parallel is the creation of derivatives as investment vehicles.  I recommend Gould's take on the subject of reification.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.06.18  

Comment: @Gerard: It is interesting that reification is also a logical fallacy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(fallacy)

Comment: Oddly, I thought to call my concept reification.  I'll respond further once I've had a chance to read what you cite.

Comment: @David, had that chance?